# Контроль над кастингом обьекта класса в String

Tags: swift, cast

Допустим у меня есть некий класс

```
class myClass {
   var someValue1: Double = 1.1
   var someValue2: Double = 2.0
}
```

что мне нужно написать что бы при кастинге объекта в строку выдавало, например, значение из `someValue2`

```
print("\(instanceOfMyClass)") // Output: 2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно унаследоваться от протокола `CustomStringConvertible`

и задать `description`:

```
class myClass : CustomStringConvertible{
   var someValue1: Double = 1.1
   var someValue2: Double = 2.0

   public var description: String { return "\(someValue2)"}
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible